# Adding new L2 Fargate service to existing L3 Fargate Service Load balancer

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-fargate, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-cdk-typescript

I have an existing service setup. 1 ECS cluster stack, 1 ECS Service stack(all resources including ALB are created in it), 1 Fargate Service stack (Default 'PublicListener' with default rule was created as a part of this) which is created using AWS cdk L3 construct(ApplicationLoadbalancingFargateService).

I have a use case to deploy 1 more fargate service in new stack but using the same above ECS Service (same ALB and resources). I found out that we cannot use 2 Fargate services together that are created using L3 constructs. Hence, I’m using L2 construct(Fargate service) for the new service.

Now, I want to assign the new service to the default rule created in the existing service. How can I do that? While testing,  I was able to do it through console but how can I do it through AWS CDK. I’m using typescript.

Comment: Please add some (minimal) CDK code to the question.

Comment: @fedonev Apologies. The code block is very modular and complex. What part of the code would you like to see?

Comment: See SO's [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) guidelines.  Emphasis on "minimal".  Practically speaking, variable names and prop values in the question make communication easier.  It also reduces the effort needed to write an answer, which will increase the chance you'll get one.